# How can I include a folder in the jar produced by Maven (not the content of the folder, the actual folder)

Tags: java, jar, maven, directory

I'm having some difficulty including a directory into the jar maven is creating. I need the actual directory in the jar, not just the files in it. 
By using:

```
<resources>
 <resource>
  <directory>etc</directory>
 </resource>
</resources>
```

only the contents of the etc directory are included in the jar, not the actual directory. Is there a simple solution for this, ideally without using another plugin?
Any feedback is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<resources>
 <resource>
  <directory>.</directory>
  <includes>
    <include>etc/**/*.*</include>
  </includes>
 </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: what if the folder is located in `src/main/etc`? Using this, the folder ends up in `src/main/etc` in target folder. But I just need `etc`.